# How can I execute an edit method for model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I wanted to know how to modify or delete (Edit async or delete) 1 or 2 models belonging to the same view

Like this example we have

```
public class FruitsViewModel
 
{
    public List<Abricot> Abricots { get; set; }
 
    public List<Banane> Bananes { get; set; }
 
    public List<Citron> Citrons { get; set; }
}
@model namespace de FruitsViewModel
 
@foreach(var abricot in Model.Abricots)
{
    // Affiche les propriétés d'un abricot
}
 
    @foreach(var banane in Model.Bananes)
    {
        // Affiche les propriétés d'une banane
    }
     
    @foreach(var citron in Model.Citrons)
    {
        // Affiche les propriétés d'un citron
    }
    public ActionResult ActionController()
    {
        var vm = new FruitsViewModel();
        vm.Abricots = // Récupère les abricots depuis la base de données
        vm.Bananes = // Récupère les bananes depuis la base de données
        vm.Citrons = // Récupère les citrons depuis la base de données
     
        return View(vm);
    }





  i do like your code,there is no exception,
```

if I click on the save button normally the banae model will be changed and I will write to index which displays this update

```
`enter code here` `@foreach (var banane in Model.personnels)
        {
   <form asp-action="EditBanane" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Id" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Id" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Color" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Color" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.BananeP" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
----action Edit
  public ActionResult EditBanane(int id, [Bind("id,Name,Color,BananeP")] Banane banane)
        {
                 
                    _context.Update(banane);

                     _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 1):

> how I can do an Edit in method public async Task Edit(int id, [Bind("id,..,")] ....)on the banana or lemon model

If you'd like to edit/update model item of banana or lemon etc, you can try these approaches.

***Approach 1***: put input fields of model item in a form and specify the action method for form submission, like below.

```
@foreach (var fruit in Model.Abricots)
{
    // Affiche les propriétés d'un abricot 
    //...
}

@foreach (var banane in Model.Bananes)
{
    // Affiche les propriétés d'une banane
    <form asp-action="EditBanane" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Id" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Id" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.Color" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.Color" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@banane.BananeP" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
}

@foreach (var fruit in Model.Citrons)
{
    // Affiche les propriétés d'un citron
    //...
}
```

Action method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditBanane(Banane banane)
{
    //...
```

***Approach 2***: generate expected data and make request using Fetch API or Ajax etc to post data to corresponding action method with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

and thanks a lot for your response,

I do like that but unfortunately it does not work yet the update has not done

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.bananes)
    {
    <div class="col-md-4">
      
        <form asp-action="ViewEdit"  method="post">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <input type="hidden" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)">


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)">


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.BananeP" class="control-label"></label>   
                <input class="form-control" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BananeP)">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-info text-white " />
                
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>}

public IActionResult ViewEdit( [Bind("id,Name,Color,BananeP ")] Banane item)
        {
          

                    _context.Update(item);

                     _context.SaveChangesAsync();


              


                return RedirectToAction("Index");}
```

Comment: If debug the code, does action parameter `Banane item` is bound with posted value? And do you get any exception of your action method?

Comment: And you can edit the original question with your updates, rather than posting new question as answer.

Comment: there is no exception ,i don't understand what you mean ,i do like this

Answer (score 0):

I do like your code,and thers is no exception and no update of the model   in the page Index (principal page)

```
@foreach (var banane in Model.Bananes)
            {
       <form asp-action="EditBanane" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@banane.Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@banane.Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@banane.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@banane.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@banane.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@banane.Color" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@banane.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@banane.BananeP" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@banane.BananeP" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    ----action Edit
      public ActionResult EditBanane(int id, [Bind("id,Name,Color,BananeP")] Banane banane)
            {
                     
                        _context.Update(banane);
    
                         _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               
    
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
```